# "Member Not Found" in HTA ie=edge after first <select> onchange

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10, hta

So I have a rather frustrating issue.  I'm building out an HTA for my company that dynamically creates some tables based on a dynamically created select tag options that then pulls data from content in a CSV file.  Now I have that part down pat.  The options are generated, selecting an option creates the requisite tables, and the tables function as they are supposed to. but what's odd is is you can select the first select option, but when you select a second, it comes up with a "Member Not Found" error pointing to the select tag.

As I'm self-taught over the past month or so, I'm not the best with javascript and my code is probably horribly inefficient and I'm missing something simple.  But anyways, I have my code set up as thus:

Select box:

```
<select id="issue" onchange="steps();"
  <option value="no">Please select an issue...</option>
</select>
```

Select box options generation (I have some radios that run the issues() function to populate different options):

```
function issues(){
  var selbox = document.getElementById('issue');
  selbox.options.length = 1;
  if (document.getElementById('blah').checked == true){
    selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('blah1','blah1');
    ***and so on for how many options needed for blah1***
  }
}
```

Code for creating the tables

```
function steps(){
  var stepnum = 1; //creates step number
  var fread = readcsv('steps.csv'); //reads the csv file
  var data = CSVToArray(fread,','); //turns the csv into an array
  data.splice(0,1); //removes the csv labels
  data.pop(); //removes the last empty line

  for (var = i; i < data.length; i++){
    var id = 'step_' + stepnum;
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var td = document.createElement('td');
      td.setAttribute('colspan','3');
      td.setAttribute('id',id);
      td.setAttribute('style','font-size: 1.5em;');
      td.innerText = data[i][1];
    var tdl = document.createElement('td'); // creates link td
    var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.setAttribute('href',data[i][2]);
      link.setAttribute('target','_blank');
      link.innerText = "Link";
    ***and so on***
    tdl.appendChild(link);
    tr.appendChild(td);
    tr.appendChild(tdl);
    table.appendChild(tr);
    tssteps.appendChild(table);
    tssteps.appendChild(hr);
    stepnum++;
  }
}
```

Where the table is created

```
<div id="troubleshooting">
  <h1>Troubleshooting</h1>
  <div id="tssteps"></div>
</div>
```

So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `tssteps.appendChild(hr);` - `hr` isn't defined anywhere...

Comment: And I don't know if it helps, but this is how I'd set it up: http://jsfiddle.net/2LTwG/ . I definitely can't test in an HTA though

Comment: Well, I found out where the member not found came from.  It apparently doesn't like being wrapped in a form tag for some reason.  The second I killed out the <form> it cleared the error.  Which now brings up the new issue of how am I going to reset the thing now.

Comment: I don't think it's the fact that it was wrapped in a form...but probably something else. Did the form have an `id` or `name`?

Comment: Yeah, the form had an id.  I've tried it with a name, id, both name and id, without name or id.  All the same.  If the form tag is there it kicks out the member not found error

Comment: `var = i` would create a variable named `var` that takes the value `i`. That is an error for two reasons: first of all, a variable can't be called `var` because `var` is used to declare a variable. Second of all, you haven't declared an `i` variable before `for(var = i;...)`. The correct thing to do is `for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++)` or `for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)`.